# Sort output in bash

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, pom.xml

I have the following script to check the parent versions of my different Maven projects by looking into their pom.xml.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Loop to find all pom.xml
for i in `find . ! -path "*/target/*" -type f -name pom.xml`
do
    # Filter the parent artifactId.
    grep -q 'IC_Maven_JEE_Parent\|IC_Maven_Parent' $i
    if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then
    # Print parent ID, version value, and then pom.xml path.
    echo $(grep -o 'IC_Maven_JEE_Parent\|IC_Maven_Paren' $i) $(echo -e 'setns x=http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0\ncat /x:project/x:parent/x:version/text()' | xmllint --shell $i | grep -v /) $i
    fi
done
```

The output in my test folder looks like the following, which is unsorted and non-informative.

```
IC_Maven_JEE_Parent ------- 1.4.44 ./AGS-DEF-JOB1/pom.xml
IC_Maven_JEE_Parent ------- 1.4.44 ./AGS-SITE-JOB1/pom.xml
IC_Maven_Paren ------- 1.5.44 ./AGS-SITESSL-JOB1/pom.xml
IC_Maven_JEE_Parent ------- 6.2 ./AIRR-COMMODITIES-JOB1/pom.xml
IC_Maven_JEE_Parent ------- 6.2 ./AIRR-DEF14-JOB1/pom.xml
IC_Maven_Paren ------- 1.4.38 ./pom.xml
```

I want to have the output sorted (firstly according to parent Id, then version value, lastly path), so that I will know the priority of upgrading. It should look like the following.

```
IC_Maven_JEE_Parent ------- 1.4.44 ./AGS-DEF-JOB1/pom.xml
IC_Maven_JEE_Parent ------- 1.4.44 ./AGS-SITE-JOB1/pom.xml
IC_Maven_JEE_Parent ------- 6.2 ./AIRR-COMMODITIES-JOB1/pom.xml
IC_Maven_JEE_Parent ------- 6.2 ./AIRR-DEF14-JOB1/pom.xml
IC_Maven_Paren ------- 1.4.38 ./pom.xml
IC_Maven_Paren ------- 1.5.44 ./AGS-SITESSL-JOB1/pom.xml
```

***An update to my post (June 08, 14:13).***

The closest point I have achieved is by saving the output into a file then sort the file, as the following script shows:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `find . ! -path "*/target/*" -type f -name pom.xml`
do
    grep -q 'IC_Maven_JEE_Parent\|IC_Maven_Parent' $i
    if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo $(grep -o 'IC_Maven_JEE_Parent\|IC_Maven_Paren' $i) $(echo -e 'setns x=http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0\ncat /x:project/x:parent/x:version/text()' | xmllint --shell $i | grep -v /) $i
    fi
done > check.txt
sort ./check.txt
```

Comment: And what exactly have you tried before asking?

Comment: No offense, but your [tag:bash] style is terrible...

Comment: Not surprised to hear that. I just learned Bash this June. @gniourf_gniourf

Comment: Well, @DavidJashi, what I did before, is to save the output into check.txt by adding the command `> check.txt` at the end, then run another script to sort the check.txt file. This is so inefficient so I hope there is another way of doing this.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf  It would be more appreciated if you can advice me a better style of writing this code.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add `sort` to end of your loop to sort the outputs.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `find . ! -path "*/target/*" -type f -name pom.xml`
do
    grep -q 'IC_Maven_JEE_Parent\|IC_Maven_Parent' $i
    if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo $(grep -o 'IC_Maven_JEE_Parent\|IC_Maven_Paren' $i) $(echo -e 'setns x=http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0\ncat /x:project/x:parent/x:version/text()' | xmllint --shell $i | grep -v /) $i
    fi
done | sort
```